# Elasticsearch _cluster/stats api vs _stats API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I am a bit confused on why I would be getting a relatively drastic different amounts for each of this api calls for doc count (Primary and Total), shard amounts, and even the amount of indices.

Does anyone know why these two API calls would return different statistics for a given elasticsearch cluster?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET _stats` will show details only about the index which you have created, and it's not included statistics about hidden index or system index which start with dot(`.`).

`GET _cluster/stats` will show details for all the indices available in your cluster and it will include hidden / system index as well.

Comment: Ah, thats strange but makes a lot of sense. Thanks Sagar

Comment: @ColeGulledge Thats how this two APIs design for different purpose.